# HTML5 pattern for formatting input box to take date mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: html, date, html-input

I used jQuery datepicker and I want to restrict my input field with a HTML5 pattern if a user, instead of getting the date from jQuery datepicker, types the date.

How can I restrict my users with a HTML5 pattern so that they can just type the date in the form `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Easiest way is use read only attribute to prevent direct user input:

```
 <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date" value="" readonly />
```

Or you could use HTML5 validation based on pattern attribute. 
Date input pattern (dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy):

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" class="datepicker" name="date" value="" />
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but the regex you suggest doesn't work for me (at least on Firefox, HTML 5). I did a small adjustment and now it works: `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}`

Comment: Ok I was maybe wrong. I have two pages that are almost identical, but for one the pattern you posted doesn't work, while for the other one it does. This really bugs me (I am a real beginner about HTML)

Comment: how to change the rendered date to yyyy/mm/day instead of mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed Do you mean, how to change date format displayed using jQuery datepicker? If so, here is the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Comment: Very confusing... I don't understand what `pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"` does

Comment: It's not accessible to stop keyboard input, and this method relies on using a mouse. Please don't use this method.

Answer (score 22):

I use this [website](http://html5pattern.com/Dates) and this pattern do leap year validation as well.

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" required />
```

Comment: Could I limit the date to only be from the past 80 years?

Comment: This is not handling leap years correctly. For example it considers `2021-02-29` to be valid, but this should not be the case since 2021 is not a leap year. It seems to consider every year to be a leap year.

Answer (score 7):

I've converted the http://html5pattern.com/Dates Full Date Validation (YYYY-MM-DD) to **DD/MM/YYYY** Brazilian format:

```
pattern='(?:((?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:30)\/(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|31\/(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\/(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})'
```

Answer (score 5):

Below pattern perfectly works in case of leap year and as well as with normal dates.
The date format is : YYYY-MM-DD

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" pattern="(?:19|20)(?:(?:[13579][26]|[02468][048])-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))|(?:[0-9]{2}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:29|30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31)))" class="form-control "  name="eventDate" id="" required autofocus autocomplete="nope">
```

I got this solution from http://html5pattern.com/Dates.
Hope it may help someone.

Comment: I'm from the future. Getting false negatives with this in the year 2021, it considers dates such as `2021-04-30` as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

**pattern="[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}"**

This is pattern to enter the date for textbox in HTML5.
The first one[0-9]{1,2} will take only decimal number minimum 1 and maximum 2.
And other similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
pattern="(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex does the standard ISO 8601 `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the years 1900-2099, taking into account leap years.

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:19|20)(?:[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:29|30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))|(?:[13579][26]|[02468][048])-02-29)" required />
```

All other examples seem to have some problem validating leap years, either not allowing the date February 29, or allowing this date in years that are not leap years.