# Input type date with specific format

Tags: html, date

I am designing a HTML form where i have to take date in "DD/MM/YY" or "DD/MM/YYYY" format and i have to achieve this task using only HTML date control. I have done extensive research and haven't found any way to do it. Can someone help me.

Comment: You need to use jquery datepicker plugin.

Comment: Or using HTML5 ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080963/html5-pattern-for-formatting-input-box-to-take-date-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: I have to use date type only and i can't use text or Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date
Or
you can use jquery date picker also for this.datepicker is very easy to use.

Comment: I did go through that documentation but there was no option of such sort and moreover i can't use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" required />
<button>ok</button>
</form>
```

Use regular expression like patterns.Refer HTML5 pattern,
Docs, http://html5pattern.com/Dates

Comment: pattern can't be applied to <input type="date"> i can only use input type date

Comment: There is no way to change date format without any dependencies,refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format @AnidhSingh