# How to extract using regex date from html format for specific event with ## (th or nd or st) from HTML

Tags: html, regex, date

From the following html chunk, I am trying to extract the date `24th May, 6:00 - 9:00pm` which is  the date for the event `Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds`.

```
    </script>
        <div class="entry"></div>


            <div class="post-listing ">
                                    <article class="item-list item_1">
                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/sally-molloy-backyard-worlds/" title="Permalink to Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds" rel="bookmark">Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds</a></h2>
                    <p class="post-meta">



</p>
                                                                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <a href="http://bneart.com/sally-molloy-backyard-worlds/" title="Permalink to Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds" rel="bookmark">
                                    <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/60258048_430912857673313_3106041492867645440_o-1024x818.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="">                                                                    </a>
                            </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
                                                <div class="entry">
                                                            <div class="whatson">
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 24th May, 6:00 - 9:00pm</h5>
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/387735931952215/" class="external" target="_blank"> Innerspace Contemporary Art</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                                        <p>please join us for the opening celebration of backyard worlds, an exhibition of new paintings by sally molloy. backyard worlds is ...</p>
                            <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/sally-molloy-backyard-worlds/">Read More »</a>
                        </div>

                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </article><!-- .item-list -->

                                    <article class="item-list item_2">
                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/confronting-contemporary-art-international-museum-day/" title="Permalink to Confronting Contemporary Art: International Museum Day" rel="bookmark">Confronting Contemporary Art: International Museum Day</a></h2>
                    <p class="post-meta">



</p>
                                                                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <a href="http://bneart.com/confronting-contemporary-art-international-museum-day/" title="Permalink to Confronting Contemporary Art: International Museum Day" rel="bookmark">
                                    <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/59806737_10156092429451716_1848756487740981248_o-1024x683.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="">                                                                    </a>
                            </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
                                                <div class="entry">
                                                            <div class="whatson">
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 18th May, 10:30 - 11:30am</h5>
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/636159330185990/" class="external" target="_blank">QAGOMA</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                                        <p>We’re confronting Contemporary Art on International Museum Day, join us! The Australian Collection at QAG brings the Indigenous and contemporary Australian ...</p>
                            <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/confronting-contemporary-art-international-museum-day/">Read More »</a>
                        </div>

                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </article><!-- .item-list -->

                                    <article class="item-list item_3">
                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/the-great-masculine-renunciation/" title="Permalink to The Great Masculine Renunciation" rel="bookmark">The Great Masculine Renunciation</a></h2>
                    <p class="post-meta">



</p>
                                                                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <a href="http://bneart.com/the-great-masculine-renunciation/" title="Permalink to The Great Masculine Renunciation" rel="bookmark">
                                    <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/58551664_10157122584896399_5017378944056295424_n-1.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="">                                                                    </a>
                            </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
                                                <div class="entry">
                                                            <div class="whatson">
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 25th May, 6:00 - 9:00pm</h5>
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/391914351653072/" class="external" target="_blank">Outer Space</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                                        <p>Sal J Edwards’ ‘The Great Masculine Renunciation’ presents a menswear collection that responds to the contemporary call for the redefining and ...</p>
                            <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/the-great-masculine-renunciation/">Read More »</a>
                        </div>

                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </article><!-- .item-list -->

                                    <article class="item-list item_4">
                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/mirror-mine-caitlin-franzmann-ben-russell/" title="Permalink to Mirror Mine: Caitlin Franzmann / Ben Russell" rel="bookmark">Mirror Mine: Caitlin Franzmann / Ben Russell</a></h2>
                    <p class="post-meta">



</p>
                                                                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <a href="http://bneart.com/mirror-mine-caitlin-franzmann-ben-russell/" title="Permalink to Mirror Mine: Caitlin Franzmann / Ben Russell" rel="bookmark">
                                    <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/59447604_2188861394528839_6705394841930432512_n.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="">                                                                    </a>
                            </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
                                                <div class="entry">
                                                            <div class="whatson">
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 11th - 24th May</h5>
                                    <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/376696563193218/" class="external" target="_blank">Outer Space</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                                        <p>Presented in partnership between Queensland Film Festival and Outer Space ARI, ‘Mirror Mine’ examines mining through the work of Brisbane artist ...</p>
                            <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/mirror-mine-caitlin-franzmann-ben-russell/">Read More »</a>
                        </div>

                                        <div class="clear"></div>
```

I am trying to use regex with a combination of (?<=...).*?(?=...) and the structure of the date but I am not quite expert with regex. Any clue?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 pattern for formatting input box to take date mm/dd/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080963/html5-pattern-for-formatting-input-box-to-take-date-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: might take a look at https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Answer (score 0):

The following function will search through a given NodeList of tags and return any matches of a given string as an array.

```js
const date = `24th May, 6:00 - 9:00pm`;

const findString = (selector, string) => {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  //console.log(nodes);
  let output = [];
  for (let [index, node] of nodes.entries()) {
    if (node.textContent.includes(string)) {
      output.push(`${string} at ${selector}${index}`);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(findString('h5', date));
```

```html
<div class="entry"></div>


<div class="post-listing ">
  <article class="item-list item_1">
    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/sally-molloy-backyard-worlds/" title="Permalink to Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds" rel="bookmark">Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds</a></h2>
    <p class="post-meta"></p>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://bneart.com/sally-molloy-backyard-worlds/" title="Permalink to Sally Molloy: Backyard Worlds" rel="bookmark">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/60258048_430912857673313_3106041492867645440_o-1024x818.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt=""> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- post-thumbnail /-->
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="whatson">
        <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 24th May, 6:00 - 9:00pm</h5>
        <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/387735931952215/" class="external" target="_blank"> Innerspace Contemporary Art</a></h5>
      </div>
      <p>please join us for the opening celebration of backyard worlds, an exhibition of new paintings by sally molloy. backyard worlds is ...</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/sally-molloy-backyard-worlds/">Read More »</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </article>
  <!-- .item-list -->

  <article class="item-list item_2">
    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/confronting-contemporary-art-international-museum-day/" title="Permalink to Confronting Contemporary Art: International Museum Day" rel="bookmark">Confronting Contemporary Art: International Museum Day</a></h2>
    <p class="post-meta"></p>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://bneart.com/confronting-contemporary-art-international-museum-day/" title="Permalink to Confronting Contemporary Art: International Museum Day" rel="bookmark">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/59806737_10156092429451716_1848756487740981248_o-1024x683.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt=""> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- post-thumbnail /-->
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="whatson">
        <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 18th May, 10:30 - 11:30am</h5>
        <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/636159330185990/" class="external" target="_blank">QAGOMA</a></h5>
      </div>
      <p>We’re confronting Contemporary Art on International Museum Day, join us! The Australian Collection at QAG brings the Indigenous and contemporary Australian ...</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/confronting-contemporary-art-international-museum-day/">Read More »</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </article>
  <!-- .item-list -->

  <article class="item-list item_3">
    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/the-great-masculine-renunciation/" title="Permalink to The Great Masculine Renunciation" rel="bookmark">The Great Masculine Renunciation</a></h2>
    <p class="post-meta"></p>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://bneart.com/the-great-masculine-renunciation/" title="Permalink to The Great Masculine Renunciation" rel="bookmark">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/58551664_10157122584896399_5017378944056295424_n-1.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt=""> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- post-thumbnail /-->
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="whatson">
        <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 25th May, 6:00 - 9:00pm</h5>
        <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/391914351653072/" class="external" target="_blank">Outer Space</a></h5>
      </div>
      <p>Sal J Edwards’ ‘The Great Masculine Renunciation’ presents a menswear collection that responds to the contemporary call for the redefining and ...</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/the-great-masculine-renunciation/">Read More »</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </article>
  <!-- .item-list -->

  <article class="item-list item_4">
    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="http://bneart.com/mirror-mine-caitlin-franzmann-ben-russell/" title="Permalink to Mirror Mine: Caitlin Franzmann / Ben Russell" rel="bookmark">Mirror Mine: Caitlin Franzmann / Ben Russell</a></h2>
    <p class="post-meta"></p>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://bneart.com/mirror-mine-caitlin-franzmann-ben-russell/" title="Permalink to Mirror Mine: Caitlin Franzmann / Ben Russell" rel="bookmark">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="./Art_files/59447604_2188861394528839_6705394841930432512_n.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt=""> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- post-thumbnail /-->
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="whatson">
        <h5><span class="caps">WHEN</span> : 11th - 24th May</h5>
        <h5><span class="caps">WHERE</span> : <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/376696563193218/" class="external" target="_blank">Outer Space</a></h5>
      </div>
      <p>Presented in partnership between Queensland Film Festival and Outer Space ARI, ‘Mirror Mine’ examines mining through the work of Brisbane artist ...</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="http://bneart.com/mirror-mine-caitlin-franzmann-ben-russell/">Read More »</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
```